# Scala type bound on implemented function

Tags: scala, implicit, type-constraints

I have a generic class that looks like:

```
class GenericClass[T <: AnyRef] {
  def getHash(obj: T): String = obj.toString
}
```

As you can see, type T needs to have implemented the `toString` function in order for `getHash` to work properly. My question: is that possible to apply type bound/constraints so that type `T` always have `toString` implemented?

One way that I can think of is to use type class and context bound:

```
class GenericClass[T : ClassWithToString] {...}


trait ClassWithToString[T] {
  def toString(t: T): String
}

implicit object SomeTypeWithToString extends ClassWithToString[SomeType] {
  override def toString(a: SomeType): String = a.toString()
}
```

However, this approach requires clients to define new implicit objects whenever they want to use `GenericClass` with a new type, which is not ideal in my case. Especially given `toString` is a very common function that's being implemented by many types. Wanted to get some advice from you on how to solve this issue elegantly!

Comment: `toString` is already defined in any object, so you don't need to do anything :) 
BTW yes, the type classes are an elegant way to solve your problem (in the general case, i.e., request that an object has some methods).

Comment: Leaving outside that all types have `toString` you may find this writing about **Plymorphism** useful: https://gist.github.com/BalmungSan/c19557030181c0dc36533f3de7d7abf4

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is such type boundery, search for `Structural Types`.

```scala
class GenericClass[T <: { def myFunction(): String }] {
  def getHash(obj: T): String = obj.myFunction()
}

class MyClass {
  def myFunction(): String = "Hello"
}

val genericClass = new GenericClass[MyClass]

println(genericClass.getHash(new MyClass))
```